# Convert an Azure Website to Web Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I would like to convert an existing Azure Website to a web role.  I am running Visual Studio 2015 with the Azure SDK 2.7.1.

According to other answers, and this web page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh420322.aspx, there should be a "`Convert`" menu item in the web project's context menu, but I can't such an item.  Has it been discontinued, moved or replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should still be there if the Azure SDK installed correctly and you have all the latest Visual Studio updates.  Failing that, just add an Azure Cloud Service project to the solution:  Add >> New Project >> Cloud >> Azure Cloud Service >> Select NOTHING in the next dialog and continue.  Once the Cloud Service is added, right click on Roles >> Add >> Web Role Project in Solution.

Comment: Thank you.  That's the road I went down in the end.  I really have no idea what's happened to that context menu item though.  A colleague running the same solution doesn't have it either.